# Separating a column as a result in a query basing from row values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Since I am a newbie, I don't know how to name this question correctly.

Suppose I have a table of fruits like this below.

```
id  color   |name
------------------------
1   red     |apple
2   yellow  |banana
3   red     |strawberry
4   red     |red grapes
5   yellow  |mango
```

What type of select statement in SQL Server do I have to code to produce a query result like this:

```
red        | yellow
--------------------
apple      |banana 
strawberry |mango
red grapes |
```

I am trying to make a query in Microsoft Access database.

All I wanted to do is to make a query that would separate the red colored fruits from the yellow ones in columns.

Comment: Instructions unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: I have that table above with the id, color, name columns. And I wanted to run a query where I would have the columns red and yellow along with the corresponding fruits as a result. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will this only be red and yellow?

Comment: I am just showing an example here. The problem I am trying to solve would have the same solution as to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the result set you wanted, but it might be close enough?

```
SELECT (SELECT Name FROM Fruit Where Color = 'red'),
       (SELECT Name FROM Fruit Where Color = 'yellow')
```

**UPDATE**

The solution above does not work in Access, but the one below should:

```
SELECT 
IIF(Color = 'red', Name, '') AS 'Red',
IIF(Color = 'yellow', Name, '') AS 'Yellow' 
FROM Fruits;
```

Comment: The version of MsAccess that I am using seems to not accept this syntax.

Comment: Ah, sorry, since you wrote MSSql I over read the Access below.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough too, sorry. Thanks for answering anyway. Is it possible? All I want to do is generate a query that would separate the red colored fruits from the yellow colored ones.

Comment: I've added another version that should work in access

Comment: This almost solved it, very close. Try making a demo about this problem in access and run the query above. It doesn't meet the output I wanted. I guess i'll just be making two separate queries, one for red colored fruits and one for the yellow ones. phew.

Comment: I did run it in access. That's why I said 'might be close enough'. I'm not sure if it's possible in access to get two items into 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Isnull(CASE color
                WHEN 'red' THEN name
              END, '') red,
       Isnull(CASE color
                WHEN 'yellow' THEN name
              END, '') yellow
FROM   fruits
```

Comment: @RicardoGreen tag your questions properly!! You have asked **"What type of select statement in mssql do I have to code "** This will work in MSSQL am not sure about MSACCESS

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that MsSQL is different from MSACCESS sql.

Comment: @RicardoGreen - even am not sure about the difference but this will work in MSSQL. You just have a try in MSACCESS with this code